# Ruby object oriented inheritance

Tags: ruby

I am writing a banking program. Already defined Bank class.

```
class Checking
    def initialize(initial_deposit)
        @number = Bank.size + 1
        @principal = initial_deposit.to_f
        @@intest_rate = 0.003
    end

    def balance
        principal = principal * (1 + interest_rate / 365 ) ** 365
    end
end

class Savings
    def initialize(initial_deposit)
        @number = Bank.size + 1
        @principal = initial_deposit.to_f
        @@interest_rate = 0.025
    end

    def balance
        principal = principal * (1 + interest_rate / 4) ** 4
    end
 end
```

But keep getting error message.I'm pretty sure the issue is within `Saving` and `Checking`; when I press s or c, errors arise. Maybe someone could help find my error. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to be more specific; don't ask "what is wrong" without at least providing some context (error message, command you executed etc).

Comment: Basically I am trying to fix the program so that I am able to create the savings and checking accounts. When I enter 'c' it says 'argument error' and when I enter 's' it lets me deposit but then says the savings class is not defined... Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So my main question is really around my class Savings and class Checking. Any advice onto how to essentially create those accounts so this program runs smoothly?

Comment: Please give the **full** error message. That will tell us exactly what the interpreter doesn't like. In general, the more information you give about the error the better.

Comment: Okay so when I enter 'c' the problem is in line 74, which is within class Checking, where my initialize method is placed. Says "'initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)"

Comment: When I enter 's' it lets me enter an initial amount to deposit, but once I do that it says that my savings class is not defined, which I am confused about because I have a class Savings

Comment: The line where you say `acct = Checking.new`, (line 74) you're not passing any arguments to the `new` method. However, you defined `Checking.initialize` to take an `initial_deposit` argument. So basically you need to ask the user for the initial_deposit, and then pass that value to `Checking.new`. _Alternatively_ you could make it so new checking accounts don't require an initial deposit. A good short cut for doing this is to change `Checking`'s initialize method from `initialize(initial_deposit)` to `initialize(initial_deposit=0)`. That's shorthand for setting the default argument to 0.

Comment: Okay thanks! So I made that correction and now basically whenever I try 'c' or 's' it's telling me that I haven't defined the Checking class or Savings class. Still not sure how to fix this part.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you use to run that Class and the errors you are getting.

Comment: The code above is the code that I am running.  When I type 's' it asks for an initial deposit and when I type any amount it says error in line 160, which is "puts "Your savings account #{acct.number} has been created!"". Error says "undefined method 'number' #<Savings:0x17ec020 @number=1, @principal=2000.0(the number I inputed)>(NoMethodError). Same error when I put in 'c' except it's in line 141 which is "puts "Your checking account #{acct.number} has been created!". Error is the same "undefinded method 'number' #<Checking:0x15ac0e0 @number=1, @principal= 0.0> (NoMethodError).

Comment: "Almost done" - that is a wild overestimation. Multiple severe issues with this code.

Comment: Also, there's nothing about inheritance here.

Comment: Do you mind giving me some feedback as of how I can go about fixing the issues that are arising?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the Bank class code here. I think the issue could be in the Bank class, not sure why are you pressing 's' and 'c'. The above code doesn't take any input.

And I assume that the Bank class asks the user to select the account type  he need to create and in response to the key he presses, the Bank class might call the Saving and Checking class and create the account.